# How to perform some calculations after dbscan clustering

Tags: python, dbscan

I have performed a clustering with geospatial data with the dbscan algorithm. You can see the project and the code in more detail here: https://notebook.community/gboeing/urban-data-science/15-Spatial-Cluster-Analysis/cluster-analysis

I would like to calculate the following in a dataframe:

- the area of each cluster. It can be calculated as: (lat_max - lat_min) * (lon_max - lon_min)
- number of points belonging to each cluster

At the moment I have added to the original dataset a column with the cluster to which the coordinate belongs.

```
for n in range(num_clusters):
    df['cluster'] = pd.Series(cluster_labels, index=df.index)
```

Any idea of simple code that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to apply Voronoi Diagrams to the DB Scan clusters:

https://www.arianarab.com/post/unsupervised-point-pattern-clustering-using-voronoi-tessellation-and-density-based-scan-algorithms

You can get the polygon coordinates and calculate the polygon area like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
y = np.sqrt(1-x**2)

def PolyArea(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html